# How to create an installer/setup for Mac with Qt Framework Installer?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, qt, qt-installer

I would to create an installer/setup for Mac with Qt Framework Installer. The Installer works well on Windows but I dont know what I must to write for Mac. This below code is for windows and linux but there no information for Mac.

Does someone can help me ?

```
Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
   try
   {
   component.createOperations();
   }
   catch (e)
  {
   print(e);
  }

  if (installer.value("os") === "win")
  {
     component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/YourApp.exe", "@DesktopDir@/YourApp_name.lnk");
  }
  if (installer.value("os") === "x11")
  {
     component.addOperation("CreateDesktopEntry", "/usr/share/applications/YourApp.desktop", "Version=1.0\nType=Application\nTerminal=false\nExec=@TargetDir@/YourApp.sh\nName=YourApp_name\nIcon=@TargetDir@YourApp_icon.png\nName[en_US]=YourApp_name");
component.addElevatedOperation("Copy", "/usr/share/applications/YourApp.desktop", "@HomeDir@/Desktop/YourApp.desktop");
  }
}
```